# Css issue with bootstrap ui datepicker in a overflowed table cell

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am facing an issue with bootstrap ui datepicker when used in a table cell that has a horizontal scroll on outer div.
When the popup of bootstrap datepicker opens, it expands the out div to its extent. Basic html code looks like,

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div style="width:500px;overflow-x:auto">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <th style="width:300px">
          Instance 1
        </th>
        <th style="width:300px">
          Instance 1
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened1" close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event);status.opened1 = true;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened2" close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event);status.opened2 = true;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I manged to simplify the problem in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0z7X33VlRfT6RKw2hMNk).

The above link contains a basic problem where I have table cells of fixed width and with maximum possibility of overflowing horizontally in the screen, I needed the horizontal scroller.

Any idea on how to make it look like just a popup over the table, not expanding outer div vertically, which is justified but looks weird.
Thanks in advance.